# Pushing sub-sub-document to array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I have schemas `countrySchema` and `citySchema`

```
citySchema = {
  cityName: String,
  schools: [schoolSchema]
}

countrySchema = {
  countryName: String,
  cities: [citySchema]
}
```

I want to push a school to the `schools` array in the city schema.

I already know the `countryId` and `cityId`, so I guess it's something like

```
Country.findByIdAndUpdate(countryId, { $push: { 'cities.schools': school } }, (err, country) => {
  //
});
```

but this won't work since I don't specify which city the school belongs to.

How should the query be? Maybe it could also be

```
Country.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: countryId, 'cities._id': cityId }, { $push: { 'cities.schools': school } }, (err, country) => {
  //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
City.findByIdAndUpdate(cityId, { $push: { 'schools': school } }, (err, city) => {});
```

Since you already have the cityId , you can simply push the school to the "schools" path in the city.

Comment: But I have never made a model `City` from my `citySchema`. Would it be a better idea to create a model for all my schemas instead of nesting all the schemas in my  `Country` model?

Comment: That depends. But if you would be performing queries on your citySchema you would be better off if you have a separate document rather than an embedded one. If that is the case, then you do have to take care to remove "invalid" cities once you have removed the corresponding country.